# Managing configs to use scripts on different computers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some python scripts to run on different computers. To avoid struggles with different paths and filenames I made specific config-files (DConfig, AConfig and MConfig) and another script that decides which config to use. It works, but I guess, there are better ways to do this. Any ideas?

```
import os
import socket

hostname_K = 'DESKTOP-K'
hostname_A = 'A'
hostname_M = ''                    # hostname not known for sure

print("start config")
print("cwd: ", os.getcwd())
print("os: ", os.name)
# print(os.getlogin())                # Doesn't work on non-posix

hostname = socket.gethostname()
if hostname == hostname_K:
    import DConfig as Conf
elif hostname == hostname_A:
    import AConfig as Conf
else:
    print("Hostname: {}, guess we are on M".format(hostname))
    import MConfig as Conf

dirData = Conf.dirData
dirScript = Conf.dirScript
pathDB = Conf.pathDB

print("config done.")
```

How it is used by other scripts:

```
import config
XMLFILE = config.dirData + 'Tags.xml'
DATABASE = config.pathDB
```

Here is an example script for one of the config-files.

```
dirData = '/home/username/path/to/data/'
dirScript = '/home/username/path/to/scripts/'
pathDB = '/home/username/path/to/database.db'
```

The other scripts are similar.

Comment: `dirData` etc. are used by other scripts importing this config files.

Comment: It might be helpful if you include the 3 config files in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a value (`hostname` in this case) that you want to use to select among
various data choices (config modules in this case). When you have situations
like this, use a data structure. **Sensible
data is always simpler than logic**. For example, see [Rule 5](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Eadnan/pike.html) from Rob
Pike.

An illustration based on your code:

```
import socket
import DConfig
import AConfig
import MConfig

configs = {
    'host-D': DConfig,
    'host-A': AConfig,
    'host-M': MConfig,
}

hostname = socket.gethostname()
Conf = configs.get(hostname, MConfig)
```